# ActiveXObject for Chrome or FF not for IE

Tags: html

Instead of ActiveXobject what i have to use for Chrome or FF.
Below code is not working on Chrome and FF.
i am getting the below error 
"Uncaught ReferenceError: ActiveXObject is not defined".

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Application Executer</title>
    <HTA:APPLICATION ID="oMyApp" 
     APPLICATIONNAME="Application Executer" 
     BORDER="no"
     CAPTION="no"
     SHOWINTASKBAR="yes"
     SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
     SYSMENU="yes"
     SCROLL="no"
     WINDOWSTATE="normal">



    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function RunFile() {
  WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
  WshShell.Run("c:/vlc-2.2.4-win64.exe", 1, false);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
 <input type="button" value="Run Notepad" onclick="RunFile();"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no cross-browser way to trigger the execution of applications on the user's system from an HTML document.

Comment: Instead of this what i have to do?

Comment: @ManoharMandal — How about nothing? I just said what you want is impossible.